# .vbproj the project is not supported by this installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, solution

I have visual studio 2008 installed in my pc when I try to open a .Net 2005 Solution with multi-projects, there are project in vb and c#. The only web project on this solution display The following message:

> .vbproj the project is not supported by this installation

I try to open the web project separately from the solution and I not have problem.
How I can open the web project from the solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a backup of the project and solutions.

Then, you could try putting together the solution yourself. Just create a new solution and add all of the projects. Since you have no problem loading the projects, that should work fine.

After that, you could run a file compare between the 2 solution files and the project files to see what was changed that might have been the problem.