# Problem: .vbproj the project is not supported by this installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.vbproj the project is not supported by this installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538720/vbproj-the-project-is-not-supported-by-this-installation)

I have visual studio 2008 installed in my pc when I try to open a .Net 2005 Solution with multi-projects, there are project in vb and c#. The only web project on this solution display the following message:

.vbproj the project is not supported by this installation

When I try to open the web project separately from the solution as web site I not have problem if i open the project as project is the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543364/problem-vbproj-the-project-is-not-supported-by-this-installation